# Does JSoup find ALL images

Tags: java, jsoup

im trying to analyze different websites to find all of the images it contains.

Now for this im using Jsoup with the following code:

```
      Elements imagePath = doc.select("[src]");
      e.attr("abs:src")
```

Now when i run this on a domain name i get alot of images but if i try to run the same thing on a sub domain i get the same images

for instance the site http://www.example.com would preduce the same output as http://www.example.com/page1

Now my question is does JSoup find all images for all subsites to a domain or is it just random luck that it preduces the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you updating your `Document` object? My guess is (since there is no valuable code provided) that you have parsed your domain into `doc` and you did not do the same for subdomain. Jsoup applies your select only to current document node and have nothing to do with subdomains/pages etc. (Since it doesn't even has to be a website).

Comment: I just figured out the problem you are right its only for 1 page at a time thank you! :)

Comment: @Antoiossss can you look at my other Jsoup question maybe you have an answer for that aswell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075085/jsoup-getting-background-image-path-from-css